# Clang AST dump doesn't show #defines

Tags: clang, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang

I'm dumping the AST of some headers like this:

```
clang -cc1 -ast-dump -fblocks header.h
```

However, any `#define`s on the header are not showing on the dump. Is there a way of adding them?

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer but pre-processing happens before parsing so this probably isn't possible.

Comment: Preprocessor macros are not a part of the AST

Comment: Thank you @AnthonyCalandra and Pyetras. Can any of you post that as an answer, so I can accept it? (Unless somebody knows a workaround I can use, maybe not preprocessing the input or something?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true, #defines are handled by the preprocessor, not the compiler.  So you need a preprocessor parser stage.  I know of two:

1. [Boost Wave](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/wave/) can preprocess the input for you, and/or give you hooks to trigger on macro definitions or uses.
2. The Clang tool [pp-trace](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/pp-trace.html) uses a Clang library that can do callbacks on many preprocessor events, including macro definitions.