# Disabling conditional macro evaluation in clang

Tags: clang, preprocessor

```
#define NUM 1
    #if(NUM)
        if(globalglobalInteger){
            result = 1;
        }
    #else
    result=2
    #endif
```

Given the above code , the requirement is that the conditional macro `#if` should not be evaluated and all code under `#if` and `#else` should be passed for further processing.

Basically I want both the active and inactive part(code under `#if` and code under `#else`) to be present in the clang AST.

- Is this possible in clang ?
- Is there any pre-processor flag available
  for doing this in clang?

Saw that there is flag called `-fdirectives-onl`y in gcc which disables macro expansion but could not find similar flag in clang

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessing takes places before parsing and AST generation, so you can't have
non-expanded defines and macros in the AST.

However, there are means for handling non-preprocessed code - such as registering to clang preprocessor callbacks (the `PPCallbacks` interface) or through the [`pp-trace`](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/pp-trace.html) tool 
(disclamer: I don't have experience with this myself).

References:

- [Clang AST dump doesn't show #defines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595807/clang-ast-dump-doesnt-show-defines)
- http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/Preprocessor-Parser-interaction-td3754583.html
- http://www.llvm.org/devmtg/2016-11/Slides/Trull-ExtendingClangASTMatchers.pdf

With regards to flags, clang has no equivalent to gcc's `-fdirectives-only`. For keeping both parts of the macro in output,
you could disable preprocessing altogether, similar to gcc's `-fpreprocessed` - which will effectively disable macro expansion (but still macros will be absent from the AST).

You could insepct the AST generated for non-preprocessed source files with these commands:

`clang -xcpp-output -Xclang -ast-dump -c foo.c`
`clang -xc++-cpp-output -Xclang -ast-dump -c foo.cpp`

HTH - good luck!